# Получение из необычного запроса значения

Tags: php, javascript

Есть URL,который отдаёт ВК - `http://l.ru/#access_token=token`.Но так как это запрос не простой,получить через GET[] и $_REQUEST, его не реально(то есть то что содержит access_token).Как это можно сделать средствами PHP или JS.(с примерами, в JS нуб)

Comment: В чем необычность-то? Да, действительно хеш из адресной строки не передается в серверный скрипт. Следовательно его надо *ловить на клиентской стороне и затем делать новый запрос* (редирект или ajax) в котором токен будет уже в GET-параметрах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
window.location.hash
```

Comment: Решил на другом ресурсе, но спасибо всеравно. Решено

Comment: @Maksym: а решение на другом ресурсе такое же? Если нет, то не стоит это отмечать как верное, лучше продублируйте ответ тут. )

Comment: @Nick Volynkin♦Такое же

Comment: @Maksym: а, тогда хорошо )